# How can I change the uinavigation bar color to solid color in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hi I would like to change the uinaviagtion bar color to a solid color with no gradient or tint, the buttons too. How can I do this with iOS 5?

Also when I set the title of a uinaviagtion bar the text receives a small shadow, how can remove the text shadow/border? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use custom images to achieve this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and for the bar button item images:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(mySelector)];

  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

or

```
  self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barButton;
```